# OAuth2.0 gmail.send and gmail.readonly scope

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, google-oauth

This question seems like a duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234974/chilkat-pop3-and-smtp-not-working-with-gmail-scope-gmail-readonly-and-gmail-s) ,But since the solution had not been accepted, I have decided to post my question.

I had been using OAuth 2.0 [LoginOAUTH2(string user, string accessToken)] for Gmail for the past 2 years or so. I had been using "mail.google.com" scope while requesting for the access & refresh token in the first user email setup.

As the scope "mail.google.com" is a restricted scope, during the app verification in google, i was instructed to use "gmail.send" and "gmail.readonly" scope as that would be sufficient for my app. My app only sends the email and retrieves the email of the user. No delete/move action is performed.

I used the suggested scope, I was able to set up the email using OAuth, requesting only for the said scopes. Check Scopes [HERE](https://ibb.co/dgXZ4rt)

But, when I try to send email using the token that I just got, i get the following error :

"Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u20-20020a056a00099400b006da76842a66sm4965827pfg.85 - gsmtp"

The method in question is following :

```
//server="smtp.gmail.com",token is the one OAuth provided
public Smtp NewConnection(string server, string token, string useremail, string serviceProvider)
{
var smtp = new Smtp();
smtp.ConnectSSL(server);
smtp.LoginOAUTH2(useremail, token);
return smtp;
}
```

The same code works flawlessly, if "mail.google.com" scope is used, however since that scope is restricted, I cannot request that scope. Using the minimal scope "gmail.send" and "gmail.readonly" has raised these issues. I use Limilabs Mail.dll and this is the method suggested to be used.

I would really appreciate your help in this matter. Any guidance to the right solution would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mixing two things.

## gmail.send

[gmail.user.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) is a method in the gmail api.  as it accesses private user data it needs authorization from the user to work.

As send is consider a write operation it can not use a readonly scope. Once of these scopes must be used.

[image]

## SMTP

Going though the mail server or SMTP server directly is not the same as using the Gmail api.

Going though the smtp server allows you to use the username and an apps password to access the users mail account without going though Oauth2.  However if you send the users standard google password instead of an apps password you will get the following error.

> Username and Password not accepted.

## Xoauth2

you can also use xoauth2 with the SMTP server but you must authorize the user with the mail.google.com scope no other scopes work with the SMTP server.